# How to show query values in LedgerTransStatement report?

Tags: report, axapta

In `G.L>>Reports>>Transactions>>Dimension Statements`, the  `LedgerTransstatementDialog` Form opens. Here by clicking the select button, the Inquiry Wizard opens and we select LedgerAccount, Department, CostCentre and Purpose and click ok. Now the selected Fields will display in the ranges grid of the LedgerTransStatementDialog Form.

My requirement is to get the Purpose (Field, Criteria) to the LedgerTransStatement report. In first Pageheader we can see MainFocus and MainFocusdescription, in the same way I want Purpose to be displayed in My report.

Comment: What version of Axapta are you using?

Comment: "My requirement is to get the Purpose (Field, Criteria)". Please specify the full field name. Did you mean LedgerTrans.Dimension[3]?

Comment: RangeValue of Range grid should be displayed Sir...

Comment: In Ranges Grid we will have a rangeValue Field (which comes from TmpSysQuery Table)... For More Clarity in CommonForms>>Dimensions..open the form u can see a combobox select purpose... In Grid u can see Description and Number i want these fields to be displayed in my report(ledgerTransStatement)..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some programming on your part.

Take a look in `\Forms\LedgerTransStatementDialog\Methods\loadTmpSysQuery` which loads the query values in a temporary table.

Do a similar method in the report, load it in two arrays instead (one for label, one for range value), then make two display methods, one for each of the arrays.

Change the `PageHeader` section to include several fields of the display methods, remember to change the [ArrayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx) property to 1, 2, 3 and as many you bother or have space.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir... But I'm a new bee to Axapta..Will u pls make it brief and let me know how it works.. Thank You So much

Comment: What do want me to clarify? Sorry, this requires programming, and if you are not a programmer, you will most likely not be able to complete this task.